# Sovereign bond CDS data

Tags: fixed-income, finance, bond, swaps, bloomberg

Does anyone know where I can download from historical data for sovereign bond CDS (credit default swaps) rates?

preferebly free?

Answer (score 1):

**RiskVar** (former Asset Macro) https://riskvar.com/credit-default-swaps/ has some free quotes (some sovereigns, many corporates). (It looks like it wants registration, but is still free.)

Bloomberg Terminal has some CDS quotes (free if you already have a Bloomberg), but I found them to be too far from MarkIt to believe.

The most authoritative source of consensus CDS quotes is **IHS Markit**: https://ihsmarkit.com/products/pricing-data-cds.html (look for "end of day CDS pricing") .  It is not free... very far from it... also it is not available on Bloomberg Terminal.

**S&P market Intelligence**  ( https://www.spglobal.com/marketintelligence/en/solutions/sp-capital-iq-platform ) bought CMA Datavision a few years ago. I'm not sure whether they still pubish their own CDS quotes, but they used to.